# Determining memory access positions for open process

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to write a utility that allows me to read the memory from a process that is currently running in windows. I have used CreateToolhelp32Snapshot to build a current PID list for all programs running on the computer and I open a handle via OpenProcess with the vm_read flags without any issues. The roadblock I am running into is the readprocessmemory function of the windows API fails to read anything if the base address given is not currently readable. That being said what method can I use to determine the readable sections of a process.

My only idea on the matter is that I could iterate over the readprocessmemory function starting at the midway point of (size of process in memory)/2 and continue until I find the specific location that will allow me to read but I believe this would be terribly inefficient for large processes (o(n/2)), and even if it is the only user-mode option how would I even find the total size of the process in memory?

If this question is not meant for stackoverflow let me know and I will close it, please do not down-vote me I have been attempting to solve my problem myself for several hours now.

Comment: for what you need read memory at random, unknown address ?

Comment: [This question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/how-does-ollydbg-obtain-the-memory-map-altm) contins the answer you need.

Comment: @RbMm I want to be able to perform functions similar to a popular program "cheat engine" in which you can read all current data that is being used by the process and monitor changes to specific addresses after you have found what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [`VirtualQueryEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366907(v=vs.85).aspx) for each range of pages in the address space to find out if the address is in use. If the other process is not suspended then there will obviously be a chance that a pages status changes between your query and read operations.

Comment: of course not for each page. this also very not effective. however of course need use this api. the simplest loop - `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;

 while (VirtualQueryEx(hProcess, mbi.BaseAddress, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)))
 {
  if (mbi.State == MEM_COMMIT)
  {
   DbgPrint("%p [%08x]\n", mbi.BaseAddress, mbi.RegionSize);
  }

  *(PBYTE*)&mbi.BaseAddress += mbi.RegionSize;
 }`

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, it seems like this will work just fine for my needs!